# Sql Server 2005 Database table is not visible whereas stored procedure is visible

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Sir,

I've a problem regarding Database.

My problem is I've Database script file.When I integtrated the script file in Database.I found all the stored procedure is visible.But tables are not visible.

I wrote the Command as follows:
select * from sysobjects where type='p'

Now all the tables is showing but fields are not.

I wrote the  Command to get the fields for particular table_name targeted as

select * from table_name .

But a message is Coming like Invalid Object name as table_name.

Please help me out to find the fields of the table ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to retrieve the columns of the sought-for table:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your table name'
```

Comment: The above code worked nicely but we need all the fields of that particular table,which is not coming.....

Answer (score 0):

You can list all columns with:

```
select * from sys.columns
```